# Сравнение многомерного списка, с обновлением и добавлением

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добрый день, есть задача. Сравнить таблицу "основная" с Таблицой "новая" по коду товара. И создать новый кортеж. При совпадении обновлять, если записи нету то добавить, и если в оновном есть, а в новом нету - то запись помечаем в поле активный False. Да кстати если есть совпадения то помечаем True, а продавца меняем на "my shop". Как можна реализовать данную задачу притом, что количество записей может быть 10 или 20К. Заранее спасибо.

```py
 import pandas as pd

list_main = (('Яблуко', 1111, 10, 100, 'myShop', 'false'),
             ('Груша', 2222, 12, 150, 'myShop', 'true'),
             ('Слива', 3333, 14, 200, 'myShop', 'true'),
             ('Абрикос', 4444, 16, 250, 'myShop', 'true'))

list_new = (('Яблуко', 1111, 11, 50, 'Вася', 'false'),
            ('Груша', 2222, 5, 100, 'Петя', 'false'),
            ('Виноград', 5555, 17, 300, 'Вася', 'false'),
            ('Персик', 6666, 18, 350, 'Петя', 'false'))

df = pd.DataFrame(list_main, columns=['Product', 'UPC', 'Price', 'Count', 'seller', 'publisher'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(list_main, columns=['Product', 'UPC', 'Price', 'Count', 'seller', 'publisher'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list_new, columns=['Product', 'UPC', 'Price', 'Count', 'seller', 'publisher'])

df3['publisher'] = 'False'
df.update(df2)
df[['seller', 'publisher']] = 'myShop', 'true'
m = (df.merge(df3, how='outer', on=['UPC'], suffixes=['', '_new'], indicator=True))
m[['Product', 'Price', 'Count', 'seller', 'publisher']] = (m[['Product', 'Price', 'Count', 'seller', 'publisher']].apply(lambda c: c.combine_first(m[f'{c.name}_new'])))
result = m[['Product', 'UPC', 'Price', 'Count', 'seller', 'publisher']].sort_values('UPC')
print(result)
```

Данный код работает , поиогите оптимизировать. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Задание выглядит как операци UPSERT в базе данных, так что не должно быть проблем с большим количеством данных, главное выбрать правильные структуры данных и алгоритм. Попробуйте начать с любого кода плюс тест с маленьким набором данных, когда получите корректный код, его можно будет потестировать на производительность.

Comment: Операции происходт не с базой данных с файлами Excel

Comment: Ну можно тупо в лоб - создать словарь с ключом "Код товара", идти по нему и делать как в алгоритме написано.

Comment: list_main = (('Яблуко', 1111, 10, 100, 'Вася', 'false'),
   ('Груша', 2222, 12, 150, 'Петя', 'true'),
   ('Слива', 3333, 14, 200, 'Коля', 'true'),
   ('Абрикос', 4444, 16, 250, 'Толя', 'true'))
            
list_new = (('Яблуко', 1111, 11, 50, 'Вася'),
   ('Груша',  2222, 5, 100, 'Петя'),
   ('Виноград', 5555, 17, 300, 'Вася'),
   ('Персик',  6666, 18, 350, 'Петя'))

Comment: @SergeyBulavka Я понял что не с базой. Просто не понятно какой ответ вы хотите получить. Данную задачу реализовать можно с помошью рук, головы и компьютера. Вряд ли кто то ее будет решать за вас. Прикрепите код который не справляется с поставленными условиями задачи и мы попробуем подсказать как его можно исправить или улучшить.

Comment: Создать словаоь можно. а потом полученый результат надо опять искать в списке и его обновлять?

Comment: Втом том то и вопрос, что я обрабатую около 20-30 разных прайсов форматирую их в единый стандрат, отсортировую его посовпадению и минимальной цене. А вот объденить с прайсом интернет магазина ((( если чесно даже идей нету как. Дело в том что я с питоном работаю только 4 месяц

Comment: Вродебы самое сложное уже зделал и вот застрял

Comment: @SergeyBulavka Обновляйте прямо в словаре всё. Потом если уж надо будет зачем-то, сделаете обратно список из словаря.

Comment: @SergeyBulavka по сути вы объединяете два множества только при сопадений хеша (первичного ключа) нужно не просто заменить один другим а смерджить два кортежа. объединение это всегда цикл по новым элементам в старые данные с проверкой на наличие уже в старом и если есть то делаем мердж и после вставляем

Comment: ok. Буду пробывать.

Comment: Добрый день помогите оптимизировать код, или может укогото есть белее интересное решение